# 2.0.7 Django Operational Error No Such Table

Tags: python, django

I am just learning Django and I am attempting to make my own app called products. I have run

```
python manage.py startapp products
```

in PowerShell to create the app. The purpose was just a very simple app to store data on products. I will also post my settings.py, models.py, and admin.py for reference

**models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price       = models.TextField()
    summary     = models.TextField(default = 'This is the default response')
```

**settings.py**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    # own
    'products',
]
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

I did then run both

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

both of these worked and detected the new migration Product. This also showed up on my admin page as shown here

[Django Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FcGd.png)

It worked as expected all the TextFields were present, but when I clicked save I got this operational error back

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWQS5.png)

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'products']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: main.auth_user__old) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1554.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1495.                     self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in log_addition
  768.         return LogEntry.objects.log_action(

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py" in log_action
  23.         return self.model.objects.create(

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  417.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  728.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  842.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  879.         return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1125.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1285.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Zac\dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

I am a bit lost as to what to do from here any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually, there is more information. For example, the table name. You should post more of the error. And not as pictures: you can just copy-paste the error into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Okay thanks I will do that.

Comment: See this bug ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31828 . It also mentions that 1/ this is fixed in 2.0.10, and 2/ Django 2.0 is not supported anymore (use Django 2.2, which has long-term support, or preferably, 3.2, as the latter is the current way Django is heading).

Comment: Excellent thank you when deleting the old version on Django and installing the new one will I need to redo anything for to this point?

Comment: No, unlikely: your current shown code looks to be compatible with Django 3.2. Just make sure your database is cleaned up as well; and start a new project with the new Django version, so that your (new) configuration file will be compatible (after that, of course, edit the file as needed).